# Redactor advanced table formatting?

Tags: redactor, table

We have a client who has quite complex tabular data they need to add to their site. Hitherto they have been preparing these in Excel then pasting in but we are hitting issues with the way Redactor interprets merge table cells.

Short of editing the HTML for each of these via source (quite laborious and cannot really expect to do this each time the client wants to add/udpate a table) is there any way through redactor to add more complex table cell formatting?

Comment: Could you give us an example of the formatting, please Cole?

Comment: Sure - we are looking into merging table cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [tables plugin for Redactor](https://imperavi.com/redactor/plugins/table/), to easily create tables direct in the editor. On top of that, I think I'd approach this using the [Redactor Clips plugin](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/RedactorClips) to pre-create a number of tables that cover the client requirement, as that will also allow you to better control the way tables are created and also set up some client-friendly table styles.